# How to display errors when parsing with metasexp?

Tags: common-lisp

I'm parsing with common lisp library meta-sexp.

When I call a rule like this (entity? (create-parser-context str)), I'm not getting any error if the str is invalid. How to get the errors displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-match is not an error unless a rule (`entity?`) or the code calling it programs a non-match as failure.

See the [readme](https://github.com/vy/meta-sexp#readme). There is an example rule `integer-debug?`, in the center of the document, that uses a callback to report the character and position of input that failed to parse an integer.

Since rules return *NIL* on no-parse, to signal a fatal error: `(or (entity? (create-parser-context input)) (error "Input is bad!))` could be used to bail out with an error message from an irrecoverable input error.